# Higher-than-standard EBU R128 integrated loudness target?

Tags: compression, volume, loudness, normalize, broadcast-standards

#### Task at hand

I'm mostly a layman as it relates to sound design, but I have a library of workout songs that I'm "normalizing" such that some songs aren't louder than others. For that I'm using ffmpeg's [`loudnorm`](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#loudnorm) filter in 2-pass linear mode. This isn't for broadcasting purposes, just so that I don't have to keep adjusting the volume on my speakers between songs as I'm working out.

#### What I've tried

At first I went with the default value of -24.0 for the integrated loudness parameter, but quickly discovered it made nearly all my songs far quieter, to a point it wasn't really usable with my current setup - maxing out volume on my phone and speakers would still be too quiet for my purposes, and every other output from my phone would be far too loud by comparison.
I later changed this value to -14 which made it more manageable, but is still a fair bit quieter than any of the original songs.

#### My current understanding

I'm a programmer, and as I understand it songs will be stored in samples which are discrete values representing sound pressure at different moments in time (e.g. wav file with 44.1k samples/s, each sample value between [-32768, 32767] for 16-bit samples). I imagine there isn't much getting around this, even with more complex encodings since it all still gets decoded to something akin to that, so it can be passed to a digital-to-analog converter.

So increasing the volume too much will make the peaks go past the representable range within the file/media format. Then you have 2 main options:

- Either let it clip (flattens the top/bottom of the wave to keep it to that maximum/minimum value), making all kinds of horrible harmonics that sound really bad.
- Or you *compress* it, which as far as I understand just lowers the
  amplitude progressively (on a logarithmic scale?) as you get closer
  to that maximum, so the wave still mostly retains it's wave-like
  shape. Essentially making it quieter at the peaks. Causing what I think to be an
  implicit reduction in dynamic range.

I would therefore speculate *EBU R128*'s choice of a -23.0 LUFS target has that in mind, and mostly tries to normalize volume to a scale that finds a good balance between dynamic range and resolution - utilizing the entire range of possible values most efficiently.  Any standardized value would have achieved the goal of ending the loudness war, so it then seems like that would be the most practical target to choose.

In essence this should all mean that picking a higher integrated loudness target parameter would result in a reduced dynamic range - at least past a certain point.

#### The question

It seems ffmpeg loudnorm's integrated loudness target ranges from -70 to -5, and I've seen streaming service songs like [Knife Party's Bonfire on SoundCloud](https://soundcloud.com/knifepartyinc/knife-party-bonfire) reach values as high as -5.5
[image: KinfeParty Bonfire SoundCloud loudnorm summary output]

It still sounds good to my ears, and -7.0 LUFS seems to be the sweet spot where most of my songs stay at roughly their original volume. So seen as the default is -24.0, is there any practical disadvantage to setting it so high?

Might be worth to mention I'm not looking for audiophile quality - an answer from that point of view would also be appreciated, but as mentioned I'm just trying to play some workout music on some average consumer speakers.